# Don't advance page numbers on \part pages

Tags: page-numbering, parts

I'm using the `book` class and have several parts to my book. There are multiple questions on the site about *whitening* page numbers on `\part` pages, and there is even the `nonumonpart` package for this purpose.

However, I not only want to whiten page numbers on `\part` pages, but I also don't want them to count towards the page count at all.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{a}
\chapter{a1}
This is on the (only) page showing '1'.

\part{b}
\chapter{b1}
This is on the (only) page showing '2'.

\end{document}
```

It mustn't trip up the table of contents nor hyperref, obviously.

---

As raised in the comments: with regards to the PDF counter, either of the following is fine.

- The counter does not advance on the recto and verso of a `\part` page, as is the case for LaTeX Beamer slides.
- The counter receives a dummy value on the recto and verso of a `\part`. The famous book *"Computer Organisation & Design"* by Patterson & Hennessy, published in print and online, uses exactly this approach: as you can see below, chapter 1 ends on page 54, but in the digital version, it is followed by page `54.e1` to `54.e14` for further reading.

[image: PDF counter]

In my case, if the page after the `\part` pages is page 54, the recto could be e.g. `54.partpage1` and the verso `54.partpage2`.

Comment: well you can substract 2 from the number at the begin of the chapter. But if you plan to use hyperref or to view and print specific page of your pdf, consider that it will be quite confusing or lead to wrong links if pages have no unique number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course, if we don't show a page number in the output, it makes little sense to make hyperref see anything different.

Comment: there is always a page number. That you don't see it on the paper doesn't mean that it isn't there. So which number should your pdf reader show for such pages? And what would you write into the page selection box of your printer driver to print out the "part a" page and the chapter a1 page?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, fair enough. Freeze the page number, and make sure hyperref only links to that page when referring to the part, not that page number.

Comment: you don't understand. It is not only hyperref. In a pdf a page has *always* a number. Compile the example in the answer and then open it in a pdfviewer and look at the page count and consider if the users can handle things like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vBZE.png

Comment: @Mew I couldn't make my solution work unfortunately so I have deleted it, `hyperref` is causing issues with it so it isn't as trivial as I originally thought and I am not sure if what you want is possible with `hyperref` per Ulrike's comments. Hope someone can answer :)

Comment: @JamesT Hyperref wasn't the only problem; your fixed definitely did something, where now indeed the first chapter has page number 1, *but* the part page is on a verso and has no blank page after it. It should be toc(r)-blank(v)-part(r)-blank(v)-chapter(r), now it is toc(r)-blank(v)-part(v)-chapter(r).

Comment: I will edit and fix that issue but my answer won't work with `hyperref` as Ulrike has pointed out, if that is fine or manageable then give me 2 minutes

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't see the issue. Beamer animations don't advance the search box nor the frame number, but do advance the "of" count next to the search box. I don't know how they behave on printing (but I would guess that Beamer PDFs are printed with all slides, including all those belonging to the same frame). If you care about making them *searchable*, you can name them e.g. partXY where X is the part number and Y is 1 or 2.

Comment: @JamesT naturally it is fixable, you can deactivate page anchors with NoHyper, or locally switch the representation e.g. to roman.

Comment: @Mew I know that beamer does it and I hate it as everytime I want to go to some specific page or print it I mess it up and up in the wrong place.

Comment: @Mew I am not sure how to fix the code to what you want, sorry, the key definition to modify to get the page order you seek is with `\def\@endpart` though but I am not too experienced with the details of things, hope someone else can help

Comment: It is possible to have the "printed" page number (visible to humans) differ from the "PDF page number" (visible to software). For that you would need custom footer (or header, if that is where you put the page number. Not recommended, but possible. Yet I think that Ulrike's comments are to the point. Also the others comments, Including B.B. (below).

Comment: Look at this from another point of view.  If the book is ever going to be printed, sold, and listed in bibliographies, there will be problems there.  The printer will be unable to calculate signatures correctly; this depends on proper left/right alignment of page numbers plus the ability to accurately add the number of the last page in differently-numbered (arabic, alpha, roman, etc.) pages.  And bibliographers will be confused because accurate references depend on "traditionally" numbered pages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So, what about my last suggestion above? The famous book "Computer Organisation & Design" by Patterson & Hennessy, published in print and online, uses exactly this approach. Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/d7Hp9sO. Chapter 1 ends on page 54, but in the digital version, it is followed by page `54.e1` to `54.e14` for further reading. If they can do it this way, then surely I can.